# How to find the largest circle that lies within boundaries of Polygon with genetic algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, genetic

I want to implement code that finds the largest circle that lies within boundaries  of polygon with genetic algorithm.

Does anyone ha any idea?

Comment: How are the boundaries represented? Perhaps a genetic algorithm is not necessary in the first place.

Comment: find the largest circle that lies within boundaries of Polygon

Comment: Is there any constraint on the polygon, e.g. convexity or something similar?

Comment: no there is not any constraint on the polygon

Answer (score 1):

There probably is a known algorithm in computational geometry for doing this exactly. If you want to do it using a genetic algorithm and are satisifed with a *good* circle rather than an *optimal* circle, then that is certainly possible (although an evolutionary algorithm seems a bit more natural). Circles can be represented by triples of the form `(x,y,r)`. Mutation operators can bump the coordinates in various ways (e.g. a normally distributed increment). Cross over would be something like e.g. `(a,b,c) x (d,e,f) => (a,e,f), (d,b,c)`. You need an objective function. Conceptually it is area -- but it is hard to make sure that the constraints are always satisfied. What you could do is use as an objective function the area minus a penalty for each violated constraint. The penalty can be adjusted to eventually kill-off all circles which violate the constraint but shouldn't be so large that it prevents all parts of the solution space from being explored. Such parameters often need to be tweaked on a trial-and-error basis.

Comment: is there a ready code??

Comment: there are various open source libraries in various languages for genetic algorithms -- though it really isn't hard to roll your own. The hard part will be the objective function. Unlikely to be a ready-made solution, though portions of it will exist in various libraries for computational geometry.